# jQuery Mobile: how to open url hash with parameter?

Tags: jquery-mobile, routes

I'm using [jQuery Mobile 1.2.0](http://jquerymobile.com/)

It's impossible to open hash with parameter. 
Works - http://jquerymobile.com/demos/1.2.0/docs/pages/multipage-template.html#two 
Doesn't work http://jquerymobile.com/demos/1.2.0/docs/pages/multipage-template.html#two?id=33

Comment: If you're still struggling with this, I recently created and released a [plug-in](https://github.com/CameronAskew/jquery.mobile.paramsHandler) which may help you out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not supported officialy, but there are workarounds. In the [docs](http://jquerymobile.com/demos/1.2.0/docs/pages/page-navmodel.html) you can read more abot this (search for passing parameters under known limitations).

Quoting:

> jQuery Mobile does not support query parameter passing to
>   internal/embedded pages but there are two plugins that you can add to
>   your project to support this feature. There is a lightweight [page
>   params
>   plugin](https://github.com/jblas/jquery-mobile-plugins/tree/master/page-params)
>   and a more fully featured [jQuery Mobile router
>   plugin](https://github.com/azicchetti/jquerymobile-router) for use
>   with backbone.js or spine.js. A newer plugin called
>   [routerlite](https://github.com/1Marc/jquery-mobile-routerlite) keeps
>   it simple with just four methods: routeinit, routechange, pageinit and
>   pagechange.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to do this to be able to pass variables around in a jquery mobile project, you can also use global variables in javascript or use localstorage / cookies.